# Tring to convert JSON object into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native

I am getting a JSON object from a third party api. I am trying to convert it into an array of objects.

```
key: {
  id1: {key:value},
  id2: {key:value},
...
```

}

to

```
arrayName: [
     {key:id1, Key:value},
     {key:id1, Key:value}]
```

Hope my description if fully understandable. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is not such thing as a JSON object, I assume looking at your example, you meant Javascript Object.?

Comment: Lol there it is again, the JSON vs JavaScript Object notation non-sense.

Comment: @DanielW.  Well there certainly is no harm in confirming with the OP if that's what's required.  Saves us having to explain JSON.parse / stringify etc, when not needed.  Anyway, this might help -> `Object.entries(data.key).map(([k,v]) => {return {key:k, Key: v.key}});`

Answer (score 0):

**This might help**

```
const a = {key: {
  id1: {key:"1"},
  id2: {key:"2"}
}}

const res = Object.entries(a.key).map(([k,v]) => {return {key:k, Key: v.key}});

console.log(res); // your desired result
```

Check demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fsa5vmb7/)